# What should I do with this, I need to install the project on my iphone

Tags: react-native

in my react-native project, when i nstall project to my iphone, prompting like:

Code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'

Comment: Some more info would be preferred.